# Escape underscore (_) in SOQL LIKE clause

Tags: soql, query, escape

Before you point me to [LIKE Clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sql.meta/bi_dev_guide_sql/bi_sql_like.htm) documentation, I already read it.

I created new custom object thats API name is **TestObject__c**.

Now I would like to query my custom objects. So I need to find the ones that end with "**__c**".

**LIKE '%\_\_c'**

```soql
SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName LIKE '%\_\_c' ORDER BY QualifiedApiName
```

Escaping underscore (**_**) with backslash (**\**) is not working as expected.

I tried a lot of variations but nothing works. I get 0 objects in result. When I do not escape underscores, I get 14 objects (1 custom, 13 standard), basically all ending with "**c**".

I tested this in **Developer Console**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach here is to filter based on the key prefix.

Custom objects always start with 'a', starting with 'a00'. [There's a nifty Salesforce help article that lists all of the prefixes used](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325244&type=1).

`SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE KeyPrefix LIKE 'a%'`

Comment: Works! Thank you very much Derek :)

Comment: I got hard question - is there a way to query just list of objects that can be queried alone? On AccountChangeEvent I'm getting error message "entity type AccountChangeEvent does not support query".